# Understanding Java Inclusive or Operator ( | )

Tags: java, byte, long-integer

I'm trying to solve this problem: I have a **byte** value (1 byte) and I need to transform this value into a **long** value (8 bytes). But what I want is just replace the first byte of the long variable with the byte value I had before.

A example:

```
My Byte Value: 11001101
My Long Value: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
What I want: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 11001101
```

Simple as that!

I'm trying to do this (example):

```
byte b = -112;
long l = 0;
l = l | b;
System.out.println(l);
```

But I get the result -112! In my understanding, the java bit or operator should do an "or" with the first byte of the long value and the byte value. Instead, the or operator is copying the 2-complement representation of the byte value into the long value, and this is not what I want.

The result I was expecting in that case was 144, since -112 is 10010000, which is 144 when considering a unsigned value.

Hope you understand me. Thanks!

Comment: Arguments to most operators in Java undergo type promotion first; your code is equivalent to `l = l | (long)b;`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens here is that `b` is cast to `long`, and this is done via *sign extension*: the most-significant bit (1) is repeated, hence 7 `11111111` bytes are used as padding. The remedy here is to explicitly consider only the 8 least-significant bits in the resulting value, using a bitwise and (`&`):

```
l = l | ((long)b & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java promotes the signed `byte` to a signed `long` before doing math operations, and that sign extends the byte.

To fix it, you can do this:

```
l = l | (0xFF & (long)b))
```

or

```
l |= 0xFF & (long)b
```

(This works because `0xFF` is a positive `int` value. If it was a `byte`, it'd also get sign extended to a negative long.) (Casting b to an `int` here would work as well as casting to a `long`.)