# Java OR operator going insane

Tags: java, operator-keyword

At the risk of feeling ashamed for the next days... please explain me the following.
I need to do arithmetics on integers with bytes.

```
int a = 0x0100;
byte b = (byte)0xff;
int c = a | b;
```

I expect c to be `0x100 | 0xff = 0x1ff = 511`.
But it is `0xffffffff = -1`
Why?

Comment: Hint: try `int c = b;` and see what the result is, without even using the `|` operator. If that surprises you, look up numeric promotion in the JLS.

Comment: Also, just print `b` before doing anything further.

Comment: OMG!   b is -1 if seen as byte. This is fine but I did not know the values are expanded as numbers!
Hey but this is pure nonsense! How could I accomplish adding 8 bits to the end of a int value in simple steps?

Comment: Aren't there a bajillion questions of this on SO? Ima look for a few

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518253/understanding-java-inclusive-or-operator) ok well i only found one that isn't even really exactly the same... oh well. I could've sworn I've seen this before though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`b` is `-1`.
When you do `a | b`, `b` is promoted to an int which is still `-1`.

[15.22.1. Integer Bitwise Operators &, ^, and |](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1)

```
When both operands of an operator &, ^, or |
    are of a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive integral type,
binary numeric promotion is first performed on the operands (§5.6.2).
```

Consequently, `a | b` is evaluated as if `a | -1`.

```java
final int a = 0x0100;
final int b = 0xFF;
final int c = a | b;
```

I'm not sure what exactly you want to do, but.

```
How could I accomplish adding 8 bits to the end of a int value in simple steps?
```

```java
int appendDummyOnes(final int value, final int size) {
    return (value << size) | (-1 >>> (Integer.SIZE - size));
}

int remarkDummyOnes(final int value, final int size) {
    return value | (-1 >>> (Integer.SIZE - size));
}
```

Comment: @FelixDombek Sure you can. You just do `int i = b & 0xFF`.

Comment: Ok I did not know this promoting thing. Pretty disturbing for me if I have bytes from a byte array that I need to OR onto an int and everything is f... up :-( ok but as I know this at least I can get it to work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
int c = a | (b & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
int c = a | b;
```

byte b widening to int and keeps value (-1 for this value in signed int).
This value in int is 0xFFffFFff, so after 0x0100 | 0xFFffFFff you got 0xFFffFFff

As described in Jin Kwon's answer - you should use ints in current case.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the onserved behavior was explained in the [answer by Jin Kwon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631683/3182664). But note that there is a simple solution for this (in addition to the `(b & 0xFF)` that was mentioned in the other answers) : Java 8 added some convenience methods for dealing with unsigned values. So you can simply do

```
    int c = a | Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with this for your code. The reasons for your code going insane are:

> You were using integer (int) data type which is of 1 byte (8 bit) but you were processing data of 2 bytes (16 bits). In such cases, the MSB (8th bit) is taken as sign bit which is 0 for (-ve) and 1 for(+ve).

In fact the OR operator wasnot going insane it was your code. you can use the implementation similar as below for your code to function well enough:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Lesson7{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a = 0x01;
        byte b = (byte)0x00;
        int c = a | b;
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that there are different no of bits for a and c in your code

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with this:

```
int a = 0x100;
int b = 0xff;
int c = a|b;
System.out.println(c);
```